# Parsing and making modifications in file content

Tags: shell, parsing, awk

I have an application that generates files containing various rows of data separated by comma (,).

For example:

```
hostname,file_name,type,status,size(b),date,owner(user),owner(group)
server1,/var,dir,ACT_VER,29987,2007-12-03 15:52:43.000,root,root
server2,/DATA_File.out,file,ACT_VER,299076487,2008-10-15 05:12:23.000,marcos,root
server3,/opt,dir,29987,2009-05-03 00:13:23.000,user1,group1
server4,/var/tmp/xxz.zip,file,MOD_VER,400,2007-12-03 15:52:43.000,root,root
server1,/usr,dir,34299876,2006-12-03 15:52:43.000,root,root
server3,/local/home,dir,MOD_VER,400,2009-05-03 00:13:23.000,user2,group1
```

Expected Output:

```
hostname,file_name,type,status,size(b),date,owner(user),owner(group)
server1,/var,dir,ACT_VER,29987,2007-12-03 15:52:43,root,root
server2,/DATA_File.out,file,ACT_VER,299076487,2008-10-15 05:12:23,marcos,root
server3,/opt,dir,,29987,2009-05-03 00:13:23,user1,group1
server4,/var/tmp/xxz.zip,file,MOD_VER,400,2007-12-03 15:52:43,root,root
server1,/usr,dir,,34299876,2006-12-03 15:52:43,root,root
server3,/local/home,dir,MOD_VER,400,2009-05-03 00:13:23,user2,group1
```

1st query: Sometimes the file misses the information in 4th column `status` which can be `ACT_VER`, `MOD_VER`, `TCH_VER` or `CRT_VER`. I want to add an extra comma(,) in the file where the `status` is missing.

2nd query: The data in `date` column is in `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.MsMs (Ms=millisecond). I want to ignore the milliseconds.

I'm looking for something in awk(other anything else) to do both, which is light in processing, as the code has to parse millions of lines.

For 1st query I tried this(& few alternatives of this), which didn't work

```
cat file | awk -F, 'BEGIN {OFS=","}{if ($4 !~ /VER/) $4=",$4";}{print $0}'
```

I didn't start working on 2nd query yet.

I was also wondering, if I should put the whole file in array and process the 4th element to contain extra comma(,) when the `*VER*` is missing and remove the `.000` in 6th element.

Not sure which one will be least process intensive.

I'm using shell script on RHEL 6.7 OS

Comment: Show expected output for the input you've shown.

Comment: @anubhava thanks, I totally forgot that. I've edited my query.

Comment: The last edit had some mistakes. I've corrected that.

Comment: @Marcos: your output is still incorrect `server4` is still having `000` in date

Comment: @Inian updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i tested ok
GNU Awk 3.1.7

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN {OFS=","}{if ($4 !~ /VER/) $4=","$4;}{print $0}' temp|awk -F, 'BEGIN {OFS=","}{$6=substr($6,0,19)}{print}'
server1,/var,dir,ACT_VER,29987,2007-12-03 15:52:43,root,root
server2,/DATA_File.out,file,ACT_VER,299076487,2008-10-15 05:12:23,marcos,root
server3,/opt,dir,,29987,2009-05-03 00:13:23,user1,group1
server4,/var/tmp/xxz.zip,file,MOD_VER,400,2007-12-03 15:52:43,root,root
server1,/usr,dir,,34299876,2006-12-03 15:52:43,root,root
server3,/local/home,dir,MOD_VER,400,2009-05-03 00:13:23,user2,group1
```

Comment: I had tested it, it didn't work, hence trying both "$4" and $4.

Comment: have a test with my cmd

Comment: the 1st awk statement is working...I wrote it a bit wrong earlier. Also, the 2nd awk statement has a `temp`, not sure if that is required. I ran both the awk statements w/o `temp` and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Do it in two steps,

1. For lines that do not contain `$4` as `VER`, insert a `,` before the actual `$4`. Since the `,` is a input and output field separator here, one cannot use `FS` directly
2. For all the lines on the date column, i.e. on `$6`, use the `split()` function on `.` and print the part without the `000`

   ```
   awk 'function splitdate(var) {
            n=split(var,a,".")
            return a[1] 
        } 
        BEGIN{ FS=OFS="," } 
        NR>1 && $4 !~ /VER/{ $4=","$4; $5=splitdate($5); print; next }
        { $6=splitdate($6) }1' file
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You may use this `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} NR>1 && NF<8 && $4 !~ /VER$/{$4 = OFS $4}
     {sub(/\.[0-9]{3},/, ",")} 1' file
```

```
hostname,file_name,type,status,size(b),date,owner(user),owner(group)
server1,/var,dir,ACT_VER,29987,2007-12-03 15:52:43,root,root
server2,/DATA_File.out,file,ACT_VER,299076487,2008-10-15 05:12:23,marcos,root
server3,/opt,dir,,29987,2009-05-03 00:13:23,user1,group1
server4,/var/tmp/xxz.zip,file,MOD_VER,400,2007-12-03 15:52:43,root,root
server1,/usr,dir,,34299876,2006-12-03 15:52:43,root,root
server3,/local/home,dir,MOD_VER,400,2009-05-03 00:13:23,user2,group1
```

Comment: This makes lines with first `server3` and second `server1` have `000`

Comment: Oh yes that's right. `$6` can be `$5` also. Edited with an assumption that there is only field with milli-sec value;

Comment: @anubhava it doesn't update the 1st line for 4th column. Also 2nd part of awk statement didn't work, it didn't replace the `.000`.

Comment: There is no `.000` in my shown output. Also 4th column in first line already has `ACT_VER` so it doesn't need to be updated.